# Why is there a Cross Origin Error When Declaring Link In React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Thank you for your time. I am having trouble making this Link work in react. I have used BrowserRouter and Passed the router a path and a component. However I still get a cross origin Error and Help would be awesome. Here is the code

```
    class Products extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-4">
            <div className="card">
              <img
                className="card-img-top"
                src="/images/pathToYourImage.png"
                alt="Card cap"
              />
              <div className="card-body">
                <h4 className="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p className="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <Link to="/">
                <div className="btn btn-primary">
                  Go somewhere
                </div>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-4">Product Two</div>
          <div className="col-4">Product Three</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Products;
```

Comment: Please post the exact error that you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no reason to include Route or BrowserRouter 
`<Link to="/"><div className="btn btn-outline-primary">Go Somewhere</div></Link>`
worked fine after checking indentation

Answer (score 0):

Cross origin resource sharing (cors) is disabled for security reasons, you will need to manually enable it. 
I use a package called **cors** for express based backend.

**Step 1**

```
npm install cors
```

**Step 2**

```
const cors = require('cors')
```

**Final step**

```
app.use(cors())
```

This will enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for all routes. You can also enable for individual routes. Check the doc on [github](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Comment: Useful info but this is not referencing a resource out of the app

Comment: As far as I know, CORS is a banckend error, not frontend.

Comment: Yeah it is more backend related issue than frontend, As I mentioned that example is for express based backend app, ie you might want to enable your backend like that. Also, I intentionally gave this example to help someone who might encounter this error for the first time to understand what it means etc..